# Change in ANR reporting

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

On September 1st we saw a significant increase in ANRs as reported on the Google Play Console. We've been struggling to figure out what may be causing them since we did not have any new releases around that time.

Today, looking in the Statistics section we saw a message that says:

> August 30, 2021 17:00 Change in reporting data
> On this date, we made a change to the way ANRs are reported to include ANRs without stack traces. As a result you may see an increase in the number of ANRs reported. These ANRs were already included in your ANR rate, so this metric is not affected.

However, we cannot find any more information about this. Does anyone have more information about this change that can help us understand the significant impact on our ANRs?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: From my experience it could be a weird Coincidence, don't rule out any other option, it may be a bug that just maifested in the worst timing.

Comment: Also in 30 Aug a lot of agreement were changed and took effect, it could be from push notification for example or analytics ... Etc.